# axios + DRF (django): multipart/form: How to pass array

Tags: axios, multipartform-data

I have to pass an array in the Formdata using axios because i have an image also.

```
data = {
    "photo": {
        "0": ...
    },
    "services": [
        2,
        3,
        1
    ],
    "name": "tet",
    "location": "123",
    "phone": "232323"
}
```

And this is my axios

```
const url = "api/store/";
const auth = {
headers: {
  "Content-Type": false,
},
};
const formData = new FormData();
for (const key in data) {
if (key === "photo") {
  if (data[key][0] !== undefined) {
    formData.append(key, data[key][0]);
  }
} else {
  formData.append(key, data[key]);
}
}
const promise = axiosInstance.post(url, formData, auth);
return promise;
```

Now how to send `services` as an array in `formData`

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending array like this through a multipart/form-data the
`request.data` `QueryDict` which python uses internally represents all the posted data as strings, which is causing the failure.

In your case the data you are sending with axios comes into python like so

```py
QueryDict({
    "photo": ["file"],
    "services": ['2,3,1'],
    "name": ["tet"],
    "location": ["123"],
    "phone": ["232323"],
})
```

We need to modify it so that it looks like this

```py
QueryDict({
    "photo": ["file"],
    "services": [2, 3, 1],
    "name": ["tet"],
    "location": ["123"],
    "phone": ["232323"],
})
```

You can overwrite your serializer or your viewsets create method to acheive this

```py
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # override create method when posting as multipart/form-data
    # services are sent as a string from the frontend
    # so we need to convert it to a list
    services = request.data.get("services", None)
    if services and isinstance(services, str):
        request.data._mutable = True  # make QueryDict mutable to perform updates
        parsed_services = services.split(",")  # services are of form ["1,5,9"] now
        services = [int(s) for s in parsed_services]
        request.data.setlist("services", services)  # set as a list in the request
        request.data._mutable = False  # make the QueryDict immutable again

    return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

ref:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/?from=olddocs#django.http.QueryDict